# Execute a shell script through php variable input

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, variables

I am trying to run a shell script through a PHP variable form, the shell script is working fine on the terminal but not executing through PHP form.

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    if(empty($user ) || empty($password )) {
        echo "<h2>You must fill in all fields</h2>\n" ;
        die ("Click Back to start again.");
    }
    echo "<h2>You Entered the following information:</h2>";
    echo "<b>USER Name</b><br><br/>";
    echo $user;
    echo "<br><br><b>Pass</b><br><br/>";
    echo $password;

    echo shell_exec("sh /var/www/myfolder/user.sh $user $password");
?>
```

Comment: What error message you get?

Comment: @Vipin : Why are you tagging this _bash_? There is no bash involved.

Comment: @Vipin : Your shell script will break if the user name or the password contains a space. In particular for the password, this could be an issue.

Comment: @Ogreucha, It's not executing the bash command. No error on the error log. When I tried it over terminal with './user.sh' it is working properly

Comment: You can try by escaping your args: `shell_exec("sh /var/www/myfolder/user.sh ".escapeshellarg($user)." ".escapeshellarg($password))`

Comment: Build the command with $cmd = "sh /var/www/myfolder/user.sh " . $user . " " . $password; then run the command with shell_exec($cmd); You may want to redirect the output to a file also to ensure it is running and so $cmd = "sh /var/www/myfolder/user.sh " . $user . " " . $password . " > /tmp/somefilename";

Comment: Check your apache error_log file.  PHP messages will be there, assuming your PHP runs within Apache.

Comment: Let's just hope nobody's password ends with `;rm -rf /` or similar. (sanitize, validate and escape your input)